# comma from form removed in recordset in asp

Tags: html, forms, asp-classic, adodb, recordset

I am no ASP-coder, but our client have an old ASP site, that they use internally.

It have recently been moved to a new server and that have caused some problems.

I a form you can input some measurements, f.x. `8,6` but when it is returned from a ASP script the comma is removed, so `8,6` have become `86`

I have narrowed it down, to about this:

```
set rs1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

and after this:

```
sql1 = "SELECT * FROM husdel WHERE id = " & Session("husdelid")
rs1.open sql1, conn, 3, 3
```

If I do `response.Write(rs1("l"))` it will output "86", but if I do `Response.Write(request.form("l"))` it will output "8,6" where `l` is the name of the input field in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this a the correct fix, but it seems to work.

```
replace(request.form("l"), ",", ".")
```

was used to replace a comma with a dot, but that was messing up the look in the database as numbers is comma separated.

Changing it to `replace(request.form("l"), ".", ",")` seems to have fixed it - for now.